# The modal appears but the profile edit form don't appear on it, any idea why?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

On my social app that I'm working on, there's still one issue. On my ProfileDetailView, to click on "Edit Profile" the modal form appear but there's no form. It was working before but when I fixed the close button and I don't know what happened.. I copied the modal html from bootstrap so i probably deleted/changed something and forgot to re-do it..
Form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile, Post, Comment

class ProfileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'avatar')


class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols': 30}))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('content', 'picture')


class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add a comment...', 'class':'comment'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, resolve_url, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from itertools import chain


from .models import Relationship, Post, Profile, Like
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, DetailView
from .forms import ProfileModelForm, PostModelForm, CommentModelForm

def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        profiles = Profile.objects.filter(slug__contains=searched)
        return render(request, 'network/search.html',
        {'searched':searched,
        'profiles':profiles})
    else:
        return render(request, 'network/search.html',
        {})

class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["posts"] = self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()
        context["len_posts"] = True if len(self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()) > 0 else False

        return context

@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    confirm = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
        'confirm': confirm,
    }
    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    My Profile
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="profileModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Update Your Profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img width="100px" src="{{object.avatar.url}}">
        <form action="", method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  {% if confirm %}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Your profile has been updated!</div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
  <div class="row py-5 px-4">
    <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
        <!-- Profile widget -->
        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded overflow-hidden">
            <div class="px-4 pt-0 pb-4 cover">
                <div class="media align-items-end profile-head">
                    <div class="profile mr-3"><img src="{{object.avatar.url}}" width="130" class="rounded mb-2 img-thumbnail"></div>
                    <div class="media-body mb-5 text-white">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 mb-3">{{profile.first_name}} {{profile.last_name}}</h4>
                        <p style="color: black;" class="small mb-4"> <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>{{profile.country}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-light p-5 d-flex justify-content-end text-center">
                <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.get_posts_num}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-image mr-1"></i>Posts</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.get_followers_num}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Followers</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">340</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Following</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.like_count}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Likes</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-2">
              {% if object.user not in rel_receiver and object.user not in rel_sender %}
              <form action="{% url 'send-invite' %}" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="hidden" name="profile_pk" value={{object.pk}}>
                  <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success w-btn"><i class="bi-plus-lg"></i>&nbsp;Follow</button>
              </form>
              {% endif %}

              {% if object.user in rel_receiver and request.user not in object.following.all %}
                <button class="btn btn-sm disabled "><i class="bi-three-dots"></i>&nbsp;Waiting aprroval</button>
              {% endif %}

              {% if request.user in object.following.all %}
                <form action="{% url 'remove-friend' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="profile_pk" value={{object.pk}}>
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-dark w-btn"><i class="bi-dash-lg"></i>&nbsp;Unfollow</button>
                </form>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-3">
                <h5 class="mb-0">About</h5>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary float-right" id="modal-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileModal">Edit Profile</button>

                <div class="p-4 rounded shadow-sm bg-light">
                    <p class="font-italic mb-0">{{profile.bio}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="py-4 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Recent posts</h5><a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-muted">Show all</a>
                </div>
                {% if len_posts %}
                  <div class="row">
                    {% for post in posts %}
                      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-2 pr-lg-1 fluid">
                        {% if post.picture %}
                          <img class="card-img-profile" src="{{post.picture.url}}">
                        {% endif %}
                        {{post.content}}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                      <h1>This user didn't post anything yet..</h1>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='avatar.png')
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', default='background.png')
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default="No Bio..")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


    __initial_first_name = None
    __initial_last_name = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__initial_first_name = self.first_name
        self.__initial_last_name = self.last_name


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ex = False
        to_slug = self.slug
        if self.first_name != self.__initial_first_name or self.last_name != self.__initial_last_name or self.slug=="":
            if self.first_name and self.last_name:
                to_slug = slugify(str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name))
                ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
                while ex:
                    to_slug = slugify(to_slug + " " + str(get_random_code()))
                    ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
            else:
                to_slug = str(self.user)
        self.slug = to_slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.following.all()

    def get_followers_num(self):
        return self.following.all().count()


    def get_my_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all()

    def get_country(self):
        return self.post_set.all()


    def get_following_users(self):
        following_list = [p for p in self.get_following()]
        return following_list

    def get_all_posts(self):
        users = [user for user in self.get_following()]
        posts = []
        qs = None
        for u in users:
            p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
            p_posts = p.post_set.all()
            posts.append(p_posts)
        my_posts = self.post_set.all()
        posts.append(my_posts)
        if len(posts) > 0:
            qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj: obj.created)
        return qs

    def get_posts_num(self):
        return self.post_set.all().count()

    def get_all_authors_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all()

    def get_likes_given_num(self):
        likes = self.like_set.all()
        total_liked = 0
        for item in likes:
            if item.value == 'Like':
                total_liked += 1
        return total_liked

    def get_likes_received_num(self):
        posts = self.post_set.all()
        total_liked = 0
        for item in posts:
            total_liked += item.all().count()
        return total_liked

    def get_proposals_for_following(self):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all().exclude(user=self.user)
        followers_list = [p for p in self.get_following()]
        available = [p.user for p in profiles if p.user not in followers_list]
        random.shuffle(available)
        return available[:3]


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('send', 'send'),
    ('accepted', 'accepted')
)
```

Update posts html:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Update Post
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="card center" style="width: 30rem;">
        <h3>Update post</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <button type='submit' class="btn float-right btn-sm btn-primary mt-5">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views
from .views import (
    posts_of_following_profiles,
    like_unlike_post,
    invites_received_view,
    invite_profiles_list_view,
    send_invitation,
    remove_friends,
    accept_invitation,
    reject_invitation,
    search_view,
    post_comment_create_view,
    login_view,
    logout_view,
    register,

    ProfileDetailView,
    PostDeleteView,
    PostUpdateView,
    ProfileListView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", ProfileListView.as_view(), name="all-profiles-view"),
    path("posts/", views.post_comment_create_view, name="posts"),
    path("posts-follow/", posts_of_following_profiles, name="posts-follow"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("liked/", like_unlike_post, name="like-post-view"),
    path("<pk>/delete", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("<pk>/update", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("invites/", invites_received_view, name="invites-view"),
    path("send-invite/", send_invitation, name="send-invite"),
    path("remove-friend/", remove_friends, name="remove-friend"),
    path("invites/accept/", accept_invitation, name="accept-invite"),
    path("invites/reject/", reject_invitation, name="reject-invite"),
    path("to-invite/", invite_profiles_list_view, name='invite-profiles-view'),
    path("search/", views.search_view, name='search-view'),
    path("<slug>", ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile-view"),
]
```

[screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMTj3.png)

Code snippet:

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Update Your Profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="/media/avatars/11892013_911718608883264_3848632245418610369_n.jpg" width="100px">
        <form action="" ,="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="P2vu2WI916PGSbMOrXD14c9EFmfMVEk3T1vkf9rqsZC7hXD94Dq2Cjo4MVCIiEEp">
          
      </form></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
      
      </div>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but I think your rel_r and rel_s filters have wrong attributes, unless it is what you intended to do.

Comment: You can try to inspect the 'modal-body' class in your browser's dev-tools. From what I can see, your {{ form }} template-tag is most likely generating a <form> tag of its own (specially if you are using crispyforms). Check if that is the case.

Comment: I inspected it, there's a form with an input type "hidden" @NaeemKhan

Comment: Can you show your forms.py?

Comment: You can see it now, plus I added "update.html" that has a form to edit posts not profiles. So maybe you can take a look at that too if it may cause an issue @NaeemKhan

Comment: Please post your url.py as well as the screenshot of what you see when you inspect modal-body from your browser.

Comment: Done, you can see them now @NaeemKhan I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the Inspector section of your browser's dev tools, not the modal? If you are using Firefox, you can right click on your modal, and select "Inspect" option. This will show you how the form and other elements are rendered on the browser. Find the "modal-body" class where your form is supposed to be, and show me that part. Or produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can look at it myself.

Comment: Added a code snippet @NaeemKhan

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code snippet you have posted, other than the input field being hidden. Does your {{ form }} actually render on the site but has hidden fields?

Comment: No it doesn't render at all like it doesn't exist, any other way you know I can create this edit profile form? @NaeemKhan

Comment: I was able to figure it out and make it appear fully on the model but I can't make work to save the updated info then gets redirected with reverse_lazy maybe, any help? @NaeemKhan

Comment: And please how my attrs for rel_r & rel_s are wrong?? @NaeemKhan

Comment: It might not be wrong as I said depending on what you are doing. It seems wrong based on the naming of the variable. With rel_r I'd assume you are filtering Relationship modal based on the "receivers" field of the model, but there you are filtering there based on "senders" and vice versa.

Comment: Regarding the redirect, are you using crispy form?

Comment: I'll check that out and no not using crispy anymore @NaeemKhan